# Counting number of conditions that have been run

Tags: r

I have some data from an experiment where each subject was run with one of 18 different lists. I need to find out how many times each list was run.

The data.frame is structured as follows:

```
Subject1    List1    Trial1 stuff  
Subject1    List1    Trial2 stuff  
Subject2    List2    Trial1 stuff  
...
Subject22   List1    Trial1 stuff
Subject22   List1    Trial2 stuff
```

Though List1 shows up lots isn the data.set, I only want to count it if it's with a new subject. If, for instance, the above is all the subjects that were run in List1, I would have run List1 twice.

I've already written something that gets what I want, but it uses loops. I was wondering if there is some better way to go about this. Thanks.

Edit: Here is (basically) the code that I already used:

```
Lists <= matrix(nrow=22,ncol=2)  
for (i in seq(1,22)) { 
    Lists[i,1] <= i  
    Lists[i,2] <= unique(data$List[which(data$subject==i)])  
    }
```

Comment: can you post the code you wrote already?

Comment: Show us the code that you have, then we can suggest better ways to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for table?

```
> table(c("List1","List1","List2"))

 List1  List2
     2      1
```

You can do table(your second column)

Comment: Nope, that just counts the number of times List1 showed up. I've changed the wording of the question to be more clear.